# Why does IE correctly parse a text-shadow with 4 lengths instead of 3?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here is the CSS code sample from MS test:

```
text-shadow: blue 1px 1px 1px 2px;
```

It really does what the task says - to display blue shadow. But how? According to w3schools, the syntax for text-shadow is:

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;
```

i.e. 3 numbers, then color.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441185.aspx,
the syntax is:

> Required: The first length is the horizontal offset of the shadow. A
> positive value draws a shadow that is offset to the right of the box,
> a negative length to the left.
>
> Required: The second length is the
> vertical offset. A positive value offsets the shadow down, a negative
> one up.
>
> Optional: The third length is a blur distance. Negative values
> are not allowed. If the blur value is zero, the shadow's edge is
> sharp. Otherwise, the larger the value, the more the shadow's edge is
> blurred.
>
> Optional: The fourth length is a spread distance. Positive
> values cause the shadow shape to expand in all directions by the
> specified radius. Negative values cause the shadow shape to contract.
>
> Optional: The color is the color of the shadow.

But in the "right answer" the color goes first! IE11 displays it as it was intended, but Firefox and Chrome do not show shadow at all.

The question is: does IE behave correctly?

Am I going to fail the test? Am I supposed (as a web developer) to always keep in mind these crazy little differences?

Comment: I'm just posting this as a comment as i have no absolute knowledge about this, but it seems wc3schools was at it again, i (and many other) web-develeopers prefer the MDN docs, which are for the most part the best docs around, for the `text-shadow` property check [the according MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow#Values).

Comment: "Am I going to fail the test?" What test? Is this for an exam or an interview or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE supports a spread radius for text shadows. Chrome and Firefox do not. The position of the <color> component in the property value is irrelevant.

The spread radius seems to have been [deferred to Text Decorations level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/#intro), as it [does not appear in the level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property) (in fact, it says there specifically that "spread values [...] are not allowed"). This would explain why Chrome and Firefox do not support it. It is surprising that IE does, since Microsoft is known to hold off on supporting experimental CSS specifications that aren't authored by themselves until the specs have matured.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is right.

[Mozilla Developer Network Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

[w3 Docs](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html)

According to the w3 it should be with the color as the last argument.

Edit: Checking w3schools it seems you missed something, as they have the order set properly: [w3school Docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp)

Comment: Ok, "color goes first" is ok.
But neither MDN, nor w3cschools mention the "spread distance" parameter.

Comment: Yup, I missed that part. You're right. It seems that just IE has "spread distance" for `text-shadow` property.

Comment: @DmitryArestov I've in my life never heard of more than three length parameters for `text-shadow`, and i get errors with Mircrosoft's syntax on every up-to-date browser i tested this in, it might just be plain wrong, or a IE 11 only thing.